# Adding subscription for replication in sql server

Tags: sql-server, replication

when i am trying to add subscription on subscriber part in SQL server. error be like :
This database is not enabled for publication.

Can you please suggest me how to solve this issue.. 
Note:IS Adding Transaction subscription script is different ? & Adding Transaction pull subscription script is different ?
Can you please guide me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: [Enable a database for replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/enable-a-database-for-replication-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

This is the article that helped me with replication.  So the database that you are sending from is your publisher and you'll need to go to replication/local publications and create a new publisher with the databases you want to send.

You may or may not use a middleman/distributor but the subscriber is where you want the database(s) to end up and you will need to set that up as well.

https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-replication-overview-of-components-and-topography/